# PropType not giving warning

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, create-react-app, react-proptypes

I have a node project, very simple, in which I have one page, one component, and one `index.js`.  I have two props: `text`, and `num`. I am trying to use PropTypes to give a warning if they are not the correct type, or if they do not exist when I do `.isRequired`. However, they are not throwing any errors. Is this an issue with my code of PropTypes? I am using React 16.2.0, and prop-types 15.6.0. I used `create-react-app` to create my app.

Here is the code.

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class App extends React.Component{
  render() {
    let text = this.props.text
    let num = this.props.num
    return <h1>{text}{num}</h1>
  }
}

App.propTypes = {
  text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  num: PropTypes.number
};

export default App
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <App num="hey"/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>React App</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, not only is `num` the wrong type, (string instead of number) but also, `text` does not exist, and it is marked as `.isRequired`.

My server continues to run and display "hey" and throw no warnings. What am I missing here?????

Comment: I just setup this exact scenario and I get the warning in the console

Comment: It will still render fine; you will just see red text in the developer console

Comment: Well...did you create the app with create-react-app? @Tony

Comment: yeah, create-react-app @Dan

Comment: I run npm start from `my-app` directory. I don't see an error at all.

Comment: The errors will not be print in your terminal but in your browser console. And check the consol level, you might be in "warning" or something else.

Comment: @Striped wow I don't know why I did not check that thank you so much

Comment: can you add that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The errors will not be printed in your terminal but in your browser console. And check the consol level, you might be in "warning" or something else.

Comment: Great, but how can I get the warning at compile time. I am using yarn start.

Comment: This is a little late but did anyone manage to find out how to print the errors in the terminal?